# How to install gensim

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, osx-elcapitan

I am using Python 2.7.
I have been trying to install gensim corpora using `easy_install -U gensim`
but having the following error:

```
Best match: gensim 0.12.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/gensim/gensim-0.12.3.tar.gz#md5=9581467d50ec6da0097939464c422d00
Processing gensim-0.12.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-gov1DV/gensim-0.12.3/setup.cfg
Running gensim-0.12.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-gov1DV/gensim-0.12.3/egg-dist-tmp-OwbpdK
The required version of setuptools (>=1.3.2) is not available,
and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
install a more recent version first, using
'easy_install -U setuptools'.

(Currently using setuptools 1.1.6 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python))
error: Setup script exited with 2
```

I checked for the setuptools version, I found it 19.2.

Comment: easy_install is deprecated, try: pip install gensim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two thing you can do in this place
1. i install easy_install

```
easy_install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-19.2.tar.gz
```

OR

2.Use  distribution of Python like ANACONDA

install anacoda.

conda install -c anaconda gensim=0.12.4

Answer (score 4):

Some Operating systems do not allow uninstallation of some python packages. In this case, to install gensim package six needs to be uninstalled, but MacOS, particularly after El Capitan(not sure if this happens for all versions, does happen in Sierra too), does not allow uninstalling pre-installed packages.

To install gensim, just use --ignore-installed flag of pip

```
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed gensim
```

Answer (score 2):

first try 
`easy_install -U setuptools`

then use `easy_install -U gensim`

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have installed pip
Then follow this command on command prompt

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update your `setuptools` first, you have an old version

```
easy_install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-19.2.tar.gz
```

or

```
 easy_install --upgrade setuptools
```

now try to reinstall `gensim`

Comment: is the update process of setuptools successfully ? @rakesh

Comment: yes, the upgrade process is successfull. But still it is not happening @Arash

Comment: the path of setuptools is (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python))                                                                                                                    but after updating the path of new setuptools 19.2 is /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Comment: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` is the right path @rakesh . every python libs are here if you see